# Only showing "Loading" in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jstree

I have a problem that is my JStree can work in all of my browsers, except Internet Explorer 10. It's only working with compatibility mode enabled. I don't want to have to use compatibility mode to run the JStree. How can I solve this problem? In Internet Explorer 10, it's only showing "Loading" but in Internet Explorer 8, and other browsers, it expands correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already know the answer its because of jstree..you need to put some code in the jstree loading code..the solution is

```
if(window.ActiveXObject) {
            $.vakata.xslt = function (xml, xsl, callback) {
                var rs = "", xm, xs, processor, support;

                var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
                var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
                var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
                xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
                xslDoc.loadXML(xsl);
                xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
                var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
                xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
                xslProc.transform();
                callback.call(null, xslProc.output);

                return true;
            }
        }
```

and its work !!!